# Why won't tkinter's "root.mainloop()" repeat my code?

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I'm making a project to for secret messages. I`m trying to make the code repeat itself after it encrypts the message. This is the code I tried.

```
from tkinter import Tk, messagebox

print('To decrypt do -(number you used to encryt)')

root = Tk()

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
newMessage = ''

message = input('Please enter a message: ')

key = input('Enter a key (-26-26): ')
key = int(key)

for character in message:
  if character in alphabet:
    position = alphabet.find(character)
    newPosition = (position + key) % 26
    newCharacter = alphabet[newPosition]
    newMessage += newCharacter
  else:
    newMessage += character

print('Your new message is: ', newMessage)

root.mainloop()
```

I've tried moving `root = Tk()` but it didn't work. The other thing is I don't want it repeating `print('To decrypt do -(number you used to encryt)')`

If anyone knows why it isn't looping let me know.

Comment: Is this a console app or a TK GUI app?

Comment: TK is the console app

Comment: TK is a GUI framework. It knows nothing about `input()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58443720/while-loop-user-input

Comment: Sorry @quamrana it's a console app

Comment: Ok, does the link I posted help at all?

Comment: Trying it now. </>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tkinter is a module to create GUI apps in python, it has nothing to do with what you are trying to do.

To make a code repeat itself you need to use a [while](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) loop or a [for](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) loop.

In this case, a while loop is the better choice:

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
message = ''

while True:
    newMessage = ''

    print('To decrypt do -(number you used to encryt)')

    message = input('Please enter a message: ')

    key = input('Enter a key (-26-26): ')
    key = int(key)

    for character in message:
      if character in alphabet:
        position = alphabet.find(character)
        newPosition = (position + key) % 26
        newCharacter = alphabet[newPosition]
        newMessage += newCharacter
      else:
        newMessage += character

    print('Your new message is: ', newMessage)
```

`while True` means to continue forever. You would usually want to have a way to exit the loop. For example, use `while message != "-1"` this will exit the loop when the user inputs -1

Comment: after running the script more than one time `newMessage` will add all the messages together.

Comment: Move `newMessage = ''` inside the while loop (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use a `while` loop. `root.mainloop` runs a graphical program, it does not do what you are trying here.

Comment: So how do code it into python? I'm not the best with it.