# How do I make a program rerun after its finished in Python

Tags: python

How do I get this program to automatically restart so the player doesn't have to run the code again to play again?

```
import random

game = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
choice = random.choice(game)


question = input("Chose one (Rock/Paper/Scissors) : ")

if question == choice:
    print(f'I chose {choice}')
    print("We got the same thing! Try again")
elif question == "Rock" and choice == "Paper":
    print(f'I chose {choice}')
    print("I win!")
elif question == "Paper" and choice == "Rock":
    print(f'I chose {choice}')
    print("You win!")
elif question == "Rock" and choice == "Scissors":
    print(f'I chose {choice}')
    print("You win!")
elif question == "Scissors" and choice == "Rock":
    print(f'I chose {choice}')
    print("I win!")
elif question == "Scissors" and choice == "Paper":
    print(f'I chose {choice}')
    print("You win!")
elif question == "Paper" and choice == "Scissors":
    print(f'I chose {choice}')
    print("I win!")``
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [While loop user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58443720/while-loop-user-input)

Comment: put all in `while True:`

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

game = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
choice = random.choice(game)

while True:
   question = input("Chose one (Rock/Paper/Scissors) : ")

   if question == choice:
      print(f'I chose {choice}')
      print("We got the same thing! Try again")
   elif question == "Rock" and choice == "Paper":
    print(f'I chose {choice}')
    print("I win!")
   elif question == "Paper" and choice == "Rock":
    print(f'I chose {choice}')
    print("You win!")
   elif question == "Rock" and choice == "Scissors":
    print(f'I chose {choice}')
    print("You win!")
   elif question == "Scissors" and choice == "Rock":
    print(f'I chose {choice}')
    print("I win!")
   elif question == "Scissors" and choice == "Paper":
    print(f'I chose {choice}')
    print("You win!")
   elif question == "Paper" and choice == "Scissors":
    print(f'I chose {choice}')
    print("I win!")
```