# Python: Return Function

Tags: python

I want to understand how to return to or repeat a set code in case an error occurs.

For example:

```
import smtpd    

LoginE = input("What is the email you will be using? \n")
LoginP = input("what is the password of the email you will using? \n")
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465)
server.login( LoginE , LoginP)
```

I have tried to use the try function but it still will crash and tell me I have an error.

Comment: _Did_ you try to use `try`? Because it's not in what you actually posted. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html explains how to handle errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [While loop user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58443720/while-loop-user-input)

Answer (score 1):

You can just wrap the code with a  while block:

```
import smtpd  
while True:
   LoginE = input("What is the email you will be using? \n")
   LoginP = input("what is the password of the email you will using? \n")
   try: 
      server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465)
      server.login( LoginE , LoginP)
      break
   except: # you can put any error here
      pass
```

Comment: `true` will throw an exception, I think you meant `True`

Comment: Yes, I meant so. I wrote it directly to the answer so it was prone.